# Publish routes to different ports

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application that should expose specific routes to a different port (8080 instead of 80).

I would like to expose

- Prometheus metrics to `*:8080/metrics`
- Healthchecks to `*:8080/health`
- OpenAPI metadata to `*:8080/swagger*` (both the embdedded UI and the schemata json)

I might be missing something obvious in the docs; I could use some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `.RequireHost("*:8080")` in the fluent Endpoint definition builder will do the trick.